# MongoDB - Slow aggregate query

Tags: query-performance, index, mongodb, aggregate

It takes around **6min** to get the result from MongoDB, when I use the following aggregate query.

```
db.barcodes.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'company',
            localField: 'company',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'company'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'company.name': 'ABCd'
        }
    }
]);
```

I have two collections in my DB, company and barcode. If I search with text **'ABC'** *(instead of **'ABCd'**, company name 'ABC' already exists in the DB)* it takes only **0.05Sec** to complete the result.

Total **42,14,301** documents in barcode collection and 2 documents in company collection.

**Sample documents**

Company

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("615dd7873c4f710b71438772"), 
    "name" : "ABC", 
    "isActive" : true
}
```

Barcode

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("615dd8ff3c4f710b71438773"), 
    "barcode" : "1", 
    "company" : ObjectId("615dd7873c4f710b71438772"), 
    "comment" : "text 1"
}
```

**Indexed fields**

- company._id
- company.name
- company.isActive
- barcode.company
- barcode._id

Mongo clients used: Studio 3t and MongoDB CLI

**Output of explain**

```
{ 
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                }, 
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
                    "namespace" : "diet.barcodes", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    }, 
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN", 
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "company", 
                "as" : "company", 
                "localField" : "company", 
                "foreignField" : "_id"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$match" : {
                "company.name" : {
                    "$eq" : "ABCd"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your winning query is running against **diet.barcodes** and is doing a COLLSCAN because it doesn't have an index.

Create an index of that collection.

Comment: How to create an index for a collection. i created index for company, db.barcodes.createIndex({company:1})

Comment: Please share the output of:
> db.barcodes.findOne()
> db.company.findOne()

Comment: db.barcodes.findOne() >{
    "_id" : ObjectId("615dd8ff3c4f710b71438773"),
    "barcode" : "1",
    "company" : ObjectId("615dd7873c4f710b71438772"),
    "comment" : "text 1"
}
db.company.findOne(){
    "_id" : ObjectId("615dd7873c4f710b71438772"),
    "name" : "ABC",
    "isActive" : true
}

Comment: Try to create an index of barcodes._id and run the query again, if it possible with the explaing argument.

Comment: index for barcodes._id is already added

Comment: @Albert can you please make few changes in query like below. Match first and then lookup and re run the query ,share us the explain plan output again:
`db.barcodes.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'company.name': 'ABCd'
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'company',
            localField: 'company',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'company'
        }
    }
]);`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the aggregate query from the question post. The following is based upon the MongoDB version 7.

[$lookup Performance Considerations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#performance-considerations) says:

> Equality Match with a Single Join: `$lookup` operations that perform
> equality matches with a single join typically perform better when the
> source collection contains an index on the `foreignField`.

So, the foreign field is `_id` of the `company` collection. This index already exists (`_id` field has a unique index, by default). Though, the query plan output doesn't show this explicitly, the index optimization is there in the `$lookup` stage.

In this case there are only two documents in the `company` collection, and the index is not of much use.

---

Generate a **query plan** for the aggregate query:

```
db.barcodes.explain().aggregate([ ... ])
```

The explain plan output shows the following (partial output shown here):

```
  ...winningPlan: {
        queryPlan: {
          stage: 'EQ_LOOKUP',
          planNodeId: 2,
          foreignCollection: 'test.company',
          localField: 'company',
          foreignField: '_id',
          asField: 'r_company',
          strategy: 'IndexedLoopJoin',
          indexName: '_id_',
          indexKeyPattern: { _id: 1 },
          inputStage: {
            stage: 'COLLSCAN',
            planNodeId: 1,
            filter: {},
            direction: 'forward'
          }
        },
        slotBasedPlan: { ...
```

Some points to note from the `winningPlan` of the explain output:

- `stage: 'EQ_LOOKUP'` - EQ_LOOKUP means "equality lookup"
- `winningPlan.slotBasedPlan` - slot-based query engine usage

---

To find and return query results, MongoDB uses one of the following **query engines**:

- The classic query engine
- The slot-based query execution engine (MongoDB v5.1 or higher)

MongoDB automatically selects the engine to execute the query. You cannot manually specify an engine for a particular query.

MongoDB can use the *slot-based query execution engine* for a subset of queries which are eligible and provided certain conditions are met. In most cases, the slot-based execution engine provides improved performance and lower CPU and memory costs compared to the classic query engine.

The `winningPlan.slotBasedPlan` field in the above plan output and the `'EQ_LOOKUP'` stage indicate the usage of the slot-based query engine.

Reference: [$lookup Optimization (MongoDB v6.0 or higher)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup-optimization).

---

The `$lookup` stage in the query already benefits from this. The `$match` stage after the initial `$lookup` cannot use any indexes in this case.

More details from the explain can be produced and studied by using the "executionStats" option of the `explain()`.